# Using List<KeyValuePair> to store Keys and Values

Tags: c#

I'm still trying to understand `KeyValuePairs` but I believe this idea should work.  In my code below it searchs through a large string and extracts 2 substrings.  One substring (keep in mind the value between the quotes varies) is something like `Identity="EDN\username"` another substring is something like `FrameworkSiteID="Desoto"`  So I was thinking about combining these strings together before I added them to the List but here is my problem.. The **login** string below is a Unique field of strings that I need to use in a SQL statement to select records in SQLServer and the **framew** strings are strings I need lined up with the login strings (and all the columns and rows of data coming from SQLServer) when I output this to a text file.  Should I make the login strings KEYS and the framew strings VALUES?  If so how do I do that??  Hope that makes sense.  I can further explain if needs be

```
Regex reg = new Regex("Identity=\"[^\"]*\"");
Regex reg1 = new Regex("FrameworkSiteID=\"[^\"]*\"");

foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    string line = "";
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
    {
        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line = sr.ReadLine()))
        {
            if (line.ToUpper().Contains("IDENTITY="))
            {
                string login = reg.Match(line).Groups[0].Value;
                string framew = reg1.Match(line).Groups[0].Value; //added
                IdentityLines.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(file.Name, login + " " + framew));
                    //This is probably not what I need
            }


            else
            {
                IdentityLines.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(file.Name, "NO LOGIN"));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm note clear what the purpose of this is. You don't seem to be using the KeyValuePairs as pairs of a Key and a Value. Are you using them as a general pair class? It's a reasonable use (I do this myself), but I'm not sure what help you are seeking.

The intended purpose of KeyValuePair is as a helper-class in the implementation of Dictionaries. This would be useful if you are going to look up values based on having a key, though it doesn't seem from your explanation that you are.

Why are you using the filename as the key? Does it matter?

I also don't see why you are loading all of this stuff into a list. Why not just yield them out and use them as they are found?

```
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
    {
        for(string line = sr.ReadLine(); !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line); line = sr.ReadLine())
        {
            if(line.IndexOf("IDENTITY=", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
            {
                string login = reg.Match(line).Groups[0].Value;
                string framew = reg1.Match(line).Groups[0].Value; //added
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(login, framew));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you do want to use them as key-d values:

```
Dictionary<string, string> logins = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
    {
        for(string line = sr.ReadLine(); !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line); line = sr.ReadLine())
        {
            if(line.IndexOf("IDENTITY=", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
            {
                string login = reg.Match(line).Groups[0].Value;
                string framew = reg1.Match(line).Groups[0].Value; //added
                logins.Add(login, framew));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now logins[login] returns the related framew. If you want this to be case-insensitive then use `new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` or `new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` as appropriate.

Finally, are you sure there will be no blank likes until the end of the file? If there could be you should use `line != null` rather than `!string.IsNullOrEmpty()` to avoid stopping your file read prematurely.

Comment: Hi Jon-  I dont think it matters that I'm using filename as the key and I don't think there will be any blank lines.  What I have is thousands of lines of XML logs that on each line they have these huge strings.  I just need to extract or parse out where the userid's are (Identity) and the frameworksiteid.  Does that help?  Problem is that a users may show up in the logs multiple times so I need to skip over that once they have been added.  How can I do that using your last function?

Comment: A key that doesn't matter is not a key. It does indeed sound like you want to use the username as the key, and use the last example I give but replacing the logins.Add with `logins[login] = framew`, which will add if there isn't one and overwrite if there is, with the result of one entry per user.

I'd let it cope with blank lines unless blank lines actually mean that it should stop at that point; it'll be safer.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I think that worked.  Now that I have both the userid's and the frameworksiteid's stored in Dictionary called logins how can loop through this dictonary and remove special characters?  I have a function that takes a string and removes special characters but I just need to know how to set the loop up.

Comment: I assume you mean characters that are invalid in a given context (there's no such thing as a special character, even U+0000 and U+FEFF are still characters, that might be occassionally treated specially). You can loop through the keys through the Keys property and then obtain the value if you also want it, loop through just the values, or loop through the KeyValuePairs. In the latter you can build a new dictionary by making your filter take an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair> enumerable and return another via `yield`. More than that would really need to be in a new question, as it's a new matter.

Answer (score 5):

`KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` is a structure used by the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` class. Instead of keeping a list of `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` objects, just create a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` and add keys/values to it.

Example:

```
Dictionary<string,string> identityLines = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    string line = "";
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
    {
        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line = sr.ReadLine()))
        {
            if (line.ToUpper().Contains("IDENTITY="))
            {
                string login = reg.Match(line).Groups[0].Value;
                string framew = reg1.Match(line).Groups[0].Value; //added
                identityLines.Add(login, framew);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will create an association between logins and framews. If you want to sort these by file, you can make a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>` and associate each `identityLines` dictionary with a specific filename. Note that the key values of the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` type are unique - you will get an error if you try to add a key that has already been added.

Comment: Hi Jake-  You mentioned that I will get an error if I encounter a value that has already been added so how do I get around that?  There are many times that I encounter values that have already been added.  Thanks Jake

Comment: @Josh You can have your dictionary hold `List<TValue>` objects instead of `TValue` objects, and then you can have multiple values associated with the same key.